Sphinx multilingual
I'm trying to find examples or something similar on how to create folder-based multilingualism. This means that I will have folders /ru, /en, /fr, and each of them will have its own .rst files with the corresponding content.
I have a project, but it is written in Russian. I want to add multilingual support, but I encountered a lot of problems already at the stage of dividing into folders. I would be grateful for help from those who can help. Thank you!
I tried to add it but got a lot of errors. When assembling I get an error stating that the conf file was not found in the path /ru/source (it's understandable because it's not there, it's in the root directory). I didn't understand how to say to Sphinx that it lies at the root.
